# Recursive JSON jQuery to add nested objects

Tags: jquery, json, nested, recursive-query

I have a large JSON feed that displays individual items and collections. I have a query that pulls out the collections and displays those on the page with an image and a title.

```
    $.getJSON('myJSONsource', function(data) {
    var outputCol='';
    for (var i in data) {
    if (data[i].type =="collection") {
         outputCol+='<some HTML To display image>'+ data[i].title + 
    }
    document.getElementById("my_collections").innerHTML=outputCol;
```

What I want to do then display the multiple nested objects within a collection, and pull out their title and image as well. I understand I need to use recursive iteration, but I just can't get my head round it.

A sample of the JSON is below:

```
{
"_id": "5480cf2fbfd33ed3498b456f",
"noun": "comics",
"owner_id": "547f133fbfd33e801e8b4568",
"title": "Paul's Silver Age Comics",
"trailer":"5480cf2fbfd33ed3498b456e",
"type": "collection",
"nodes": [ ],
"collection": [
          {
          "_id": "5480cf60bfd33ec9498b456c",
          "noun": "comics",
          "owner_id": "547f133fbfd33e801e8b4568",
          "title": "Detective Comics",
          "trailer": [
                       [ "5480cf60bfd33ec9498b456b"]
                     ],
          "nodes": [ ],
          "collection": "5480cf2fbfd33ed3498b456f"
           },
```

Comment: You might want to format your JSON for readability as it is hard to see its nested structure in the question.

Comment: I that better? I'm copying from Postman, and it pastes as an unformatted string. The Collection key is the nested object, and I want to be able to iterate through that

Comment: @PaulAston _"What I want to do then display the multiple nested objects within a collection, and pull out their title and image as well. "_ `image` property of json object not appear at OP ? If possible , can post full json ? Thanks

Comment: @guest271314 - the full JSON is pretty huge. 'trailer' is the image ID and calling that with the server API will display the image.